# What actually happens when we do newlink.next? Don't tell me it goes to next node .Check my class and description below

Tags: java

```
class Link
{
    int data;
    Link next;
    Link(int data)
    {
        this.data=data;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "{"+data+"}";
    }
}
class MyLinkList
{
    Link first;
    MyLinkList()
    {
        first=null; // list is empty
    }

    void insertFirst(int data)
    {
        Link newlink=new Link(data);
        newlink.next=first;
        first=newlink;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str="";
        Link current=first;
        while(current!=null)
        {
            str=str+ current.toString();
            current=current.next;
        }

        return str;
    }
}
public class SinglyLinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyLinkList list=new MyLinkList();
        list.insertFirst(52);
        list.insertFirst(78);

        System.out.println(list);

    }

}
```

/*
This is My Linked List class which I made using java. We all know there are nodes and we traverse it. But one thing I didn't get it.
Link next is used 
Link first is used and we use newlink.next=first; Refer to function insertFirst()

How is it actually working ? 
next,newlink,first are class Link references. 
What actually happens inside when we do newlink.next or first.next ?

What are nodes? Are they objects or references or what ?

*/

Comment: Debugging your application and inspecting the values will give you more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What actually happens when we do `newlink.next`?

In the code you showed us, you don't "do" `newlink.next`.  What you actually do is:

```
newlink.next = first;
```

That assigns a reference to `newlink.next`.

> Don't tell me it goes to next node.

Define "it goes to".  This is not proper terminology.

> What actually happens inside when we do `newlink.next` or `first.next` ?

- `newLink` is a local variable whose type is `Link`.
- `first` is an instance variable (of the `MyLinkedList` class) whose type is `Link`.
- `next` is an instance variable (of the `Link` class) whose type is `Link`.

In each case the variable may contain either a reference to a `Link` object or `null`.

What happens when you "do" `newlink.next` or `first.next` depends on the context:

```
newlink.next = first;
```

assigns the `Link` reference in `first` to the `next` instance variable of the object that `newlink` refers to.

```
first = newlink;
```

assigns the reference in `newlink` to the `first` variable of the current `MyLinkedList` object.

```
current = current.next;
```

takes the reference in the `next` variable of the `Link` that `current` refers to and assigns *that* to `current`.  In other words it updates `current` to refer to the "next" `Link` object.

> What are nodes? Are they objects or references or what ?

I assume that you mean `Link` instances.  They are both, depending on how you are using them.

But remember that in Java that you assign references not objects.